# Two conditions in INDEX and SMALL functions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the below written formula that looks in the **securities!** sheet containing stocks and it fetches all stocks that have a dividend rate under the desired value stated in the **$B$2** cell. I have the same formula set up to work for when I need to fetch all stocks issued by the same issuer, where **!securities$J:$J=$A$2** and of course **$A$2** contains the value of the issuer.

```
ArrayFormula(INDEX(securities!$A:$J,SMALL(IF(securities!$B:$B<=$B$2,ROW(securities!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),1))
```

However, when I try to write a formula that combines **both** conditions, meaning it should fetch both all stocks under **$B$2 dividend rate** and issued by the same **$A$2 issuer**, it returns an error: "Error SMALL has no valid input data.". This is what I tried:

```
ArrayFormula(INDEX(securities!$A:$J,SMALL(IF(and(securities!$B:$B<=$B$2,securities!$J:$J=$A$2),ROW(securities!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),1))
```

I am clearly missing something and I can't seem to get this to work. Any ideas where should be the problem and how can I fix it?

**Here is a link to the Google sheets spreadsheet so you can try:**
[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bBUba3FLBwr1DZV3ksoMZSV6b2eTD19mYJV-KvEpDKg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need to use (xxxx) * (yyyy) instead of AND i believe in araray formula

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I have tried but I seem to get this error: "Error
Function MULTIPLY parameter 1 expects number values. But 'AHT' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number." I have added a copy of the spreadsheet if you have any other suggestions, you can make a copy and try

Comment: It would be something like so in Excel `((A1:A100="A")*(B1:B10)="B")*(row(a1:a100)))`

Comment: Nice meeting you on the spreadsheet briefly. If my Answer below meets your expectation, please take a moment to close this post by marking my Answer post as "Best Answer." Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the complete wrong formulas for these.

Delete Sheet2!A5:C. When you're done, you should have no formulas left in the sheet.

The place the following formulas into your sheet...

In A5:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(securities!A:A,REGEXMATCH(securities!A:A,A2)),"No Matches")`

In B5:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(securities!A:A,securities!B:B<=B2),"No Matches")`

In C5:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(securities!A:A,REGEXMATCH(securities!A:A,A2),securities!B:B<=B2),"No Matches")`

These will each produce all results for their respective columns.